# How can I assign hotkeys to specific layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, workflow, hotkeys

I am flatting pages in a comic book.

The process is always the same, and I have a set of four layers that I need to cycle through constantly while working (but there can be several dozen other layers in the document).

Is there a trick, workaround, or plugin that would allow me to connect those layers to specific keyboard shortcuts?

There seems to be no built-in way in the app right now, and no obvious solution out there on the Internet.

I'm using the CC version.

Answer (score 3):

Rename your 4 layers to add something similar to the start or end of them. Like "Working: " then in CC you have the ability to only display layers by Name and can type in Working:

Here's a quick example, then you can just move through them via cycling.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could temporarily group all the layers you're not using leaving them as a cluster + your remaining 4. From there you could cycle through the layers using alt ] or alt [ .

Small caveat in that you'll also pass across the group of layers—but now it's only one step over the grouped entity instead of many. When done 'ungroup' to return your document to its previous state.